# I can connect to server's postgres with Rails, but am unable to through the command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to connect to a server's Postgres db through a script. I've ssh-ed into the box and tried

```
$ psql postgres -U my_username -W   #And then entered the password
```

and get the error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "my_username"
```

However, the Rails application running on this server is using these same credentials. I've used `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` in the rails console and used the credentials exactly as they are when trying to use `psql`. In the rails console, I'm able to query on the database, so I do know the connection is working there.

Is it possible there's a restriction somewhere that's preventing me from connecting through `psql`? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect like this:

```
 psql postgres -U my_username -h 127.0.0.1 -W   #And then entered the password
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this:

```
psql --username="postgres"
```

Another possibility would be to inform more parameters

```
psql --username="postgres" --host="<ip or host name>" --port="<port, default 5432>" -W <db name>
```

Good look!